# Azure Functions Method not found error

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-media-services, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to setup an azure function that imports a blob into azure media service. But when i try to run the function in debug mode some breakpoints are never hit and then i get this error

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception while executing function: Functions.EncodeJob ---> System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.CopyBlobHelpers.CopyBlobAsync(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobRequestOptions, System.Threading.CancellationToken)'. at MyApp.WebTasks.EncodeJob.EncodeJobTrigger.CreateAssetFromBlob(CloudBlob sourceBlob,CloudStorageAccount destinationStorageAccount) at C:\Source\Quickflix\MyApp.webtasks\MyApp.WebTasks\EncodeJob\EncodeJobTrigger.cs : 164 at.....(truncated due to length)

It seems the cause is this block here

```
            // Call the CopyBlobHelpers.CopyBlobAsync extension method to copy blobs.
        using (var task =
            CopyBlobHelpers.CopyBlobAsync((CloudBlockBlob)sourceBlob,
                (CloudBlockBlob)destinationBlob,
                new BlobRequestOptions(),
                CancellationToken.None))
        {
            task.Wait();
        }
```

When i comment this block out i'm able to hit a breakpoint that i stuck in the method that this belongs to. When it is not commented out the breakpoint is never hit and i get this error. The exception seems to happen as soon as i step into CreateAssetFromBlob and not on the line that actually calls CopyBlobAsync. I've checked that all my nuget packages are up to date and that the version of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.Extensions in the bin dir is the same version. The project builds fine so i'm not sure what i am missing. I'm scratching my head over why its behaving like this, am i missing something obvious?

So the project is setup as a Webapplication using this sample
https://github.com/lindydonna/FunctionsAsWebProject which seems to work ok, i can debug locally and deploy to azure functions app using git.

For a more complete code snippet this is pretty much what i have

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using MyApp.Integration.Services;
using MyApp.Logging;

namespace MyApp.WebTasks.EncodeJob
{
    public class EncodeJobTrigger
    {
        private static CloudMediaContext _context;
        private static MediaServicesCredentials _cachedCredentials;

        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            var blob = Encode("vidcontainer", "vid.mp4");

            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(blob.Exists()));
        }

        public static CloudBlob Encode(string containerName, string blobPath)
        {
            var logger = new DebugLogger();
            var amsConnectionString = "connectionstring";
            var blobStorageService = new AzureBlobStorageService(amsConnectionString, logger);
            var destStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connectionstring");

            string mediaServicesAccountName = "myaccountname";
            string mediaServicesAccountKey = "mykey";

            _cachedCredentials = new MediaServicesCredentials(
                mediaServicesAccountName,
                mediaServicesAccountKey);

            _context = new CloudMediaContext(_cachedCredentials);
            var blob = blobStorageService.FindBlobInContainer(containerName, blobPath);

            ImportBlobIntoAms(blob, destStorageAccount);

            return blob;

        }

        public static IAsset ImportBlobIntoAms(CloudBlob blob, CloudStorageAccount destStorageAccount)
        {

            var asset = CreateAssetFromBlob(blob, destStorageAccount);
            return asset;
        }

        public static IAsset CreateAssetFromBlob(CloudBlob sourceBlob, CloudStorageAccount destinationStorageAccount)
        {

            CloudBlobClient destBlobStorage = destinationStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            // Create a new asset. 
            IAsset asset = _context.Assets.Create("NewAsset_" + Guid.NewGuid(), AssetCreationOptions.None);

            IAccessPolicy writePolicy = _context.AccessPolicies.Create("writePolicy",
                TimeSpan.FromHours(24), AccessPermissions.Write);

            ILocator destinationLocator =
                _context.Locators.CreateLocator(LocatorType.Sas, asset, writePolicy);

            // Get the asset container URI and Blob copy from mediaContainer to assetContainer. 
            CloudBlobContainer destAssetContainer =
                destBlobStorage.GetContainerReference((new Uri(destinationLocator.Path)).Segments[1]);

            if (destAssetContainer.CreateIfNotExists())
            {
                destAssetContainer.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions
                {
                    PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
                });
            }

            var assetFile = asset.AssetFiles.Create(sourceBlob.Name);

            ICloudBlob destinationBlob = destAssetContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(assetFile.Name);

            // Call the CopyBlobHelpers.CopyBlobAsync extension method to copy blobs.
            using (var task =
                CopyBlobHelpers.CopyBlobAsync((CloudBlockBlob)sourceBlob,
                    (CloudBlockBlob)destinationBlob,
                    new BlobRequestOptions(),
                    CancellationToken.None))
            {
                task.Wait();
            }

            assetFile.ContentFileSize = (sourceBlob as ICloudBlob).Properties.Length;
            assetFile.Update();
            Console.WriteLine("File {0} is of {1} size", assetFile.Name, assetFile.ContentFileSize);
            //            }

            asset.Update();

            destinationLocator.Delete();
            writePolicy.Delete();

            // Set the primary asset file.
            // If, for example, we copied a set of Smooth Streaming files, 
            // set the .ism file to be the primary file. 
            // If we, for example, copied an .mp4, then the mp4 would be the primary file. 
            var ismAssetFiles = asset.AssetFiles.ToList().FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name.Equals(sourceBlob.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

            // The following code assigns the first .ism file as the primary file in the asset.
            // An asset should have one .ism file.  
            ismAssetFiles.IsPrimary = true;
            ismAssetFiles.Update();

            return asset;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 1**
So i updated this block/function to be async and not wait on the task but i still get the same error. Updated code looks like this.

```
            await CopyBlobHelpers.CopyBlobAsync((CloudBlockBlob) sourceBlob,
            (CloudBlockBlob) destinationBlob,
            new BlobRequestOptions(),
            CancellationToken.None);
```

Also her is nugets packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="2.0.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Dynamic.Runtime" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="4.0.2.206221351" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Queryable" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Net.Requests" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="TransientFaultHandling.Core" version="5.1.1209.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="windowsazure.mediaservices" version="3.8.0.5" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="windowsazure.mediaservices.extensions" version="3.8.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="8.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Comment: It could be a mismatch of nuget package versions, e.g. for `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage`. Show you packages file.

Comment: I've added the packages.config of the main web project. I didn't include the packages of my shared azure integrations lib because when i copied those classes into the web project and removed the reference to the integration project i still got the error. I've tried a few different combo's of .net versions as well. It stated at .net 4.6 but i tried .net 4,5 because this appears to be the max version the windowsazure.mediaservices.extensions lib supports

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely caused by a mismatch on the version of the Storage SDK you're using. Can you please downgrade to 7.2.1 and retry?

Comment: That fixed the issue, i still not sure why the function builds fine though. Why is this a runtime issue? After your post i also found this which seems to hint at a change to the method signature https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-media-services-extensions/issues/38

Comment: marking this as the answer even though it was not my final solution. It did fix the error i was getting but i ran into another method not found error, this time with Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.StartCopyFromBlobAsync. 

My actual solution came from using code from the sample Damian link in his answer. I would still love to know why this was not picked up at compile time through?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your block

```
{
    task.Wait();
}
```

Try adding this import

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
```

Comment: any idea why that might cause a method not found exception? i did plan to make that async but i'll need to figure out how to track some state before doing this.

Comment: I know that the major of the imports are not necessary, they are automatically added by the Azure Functions. Did they imported automatically?

Comment: We also have some examples of encoding integrated with Media Services up in this sample repo - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-dotnet-functions-integration  
You may want to reference some of the Function implementations in that source code.

Comment: I just noted that you missed an import perhaps, did you tried adding that?

Comment: Yes they probably got added when i copied some azure service classes i use as an integration layer for communicating with azure into the actual function. They were in another class library and i wanted to rule out dependency issues with it.

Comment: Yeah, but in your code there is Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host; import and there is not Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs; import, and checking here I saw it uses both of imports. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp

Comment: because the error is about Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, and maybe they need to be both in the same class

Comment: Might be onto something there, the other thing is i'm using just .cs classes not the .csx. I read precompile docs that this shouldn't matter? but i do see some addition syntax in the .csx. for example there is a #r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" as well as a using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;. Is the #r the dll to load? i assume this is handled by the project reference in the web app?

Comment: Mmm... Did you load the #r? Because I'm not sure the project reference handles by its own

Comment: #r isn't valid c# syntax so it doesn't compile. i haven't seen any alternative for it. I could try convert it to a .csx

Comment: A word of caution. Watch out when using CopyBlobAsync with large files when you deploy to Azure Functions.  If the copy takes longer than 5 minutes you will time out.

Comment: @DamianLattenero I was able to get an alternative working using the azure functions encoding sample you linked. I'm not sure what method would be better. I'll have to check what copyBlobHelper.CreateAssetFromBlob does differently to the ams extensions framework